# Why does WCF Method Throw ProtocolException when inner TransactionScope is Aborted?

Tags: c#, wcf, transactionscope

I have a client that calls a pair of web service methods as part of a TransactionScope. The first service method does several things as part of its own TransactionScope. If the first method's inner TransactionScope is not completed (i.e. scope.Complete() is never called), the web service method throws a ProtocolException regardless of what the service method actually returns. Here is the full exception message (with real object names obfuscated to match example below):

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The transaction under which this method call was executing was asynchronously aborted.

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at TransactionScopeExperiment.Service1WCF.IService1.ServiceRequest(ServiceRequest request)
   at TransactionScopeExperiment.Service1WCF.Service1ServiceClient.ServiceMethod1(ServiceRequest request) in d:\vs-projects\TransactionScopeExperiment\TransactionScopeExperiment\Service References\Service1WCF\Reference.cs:line 1204
   at TransactionScopeExperiment.Program.CallAddMethod() in d:\vs-projects\TransactionScopeExperiment\TransactionScopeExperiment\Program.cs:line 60
   at TransactionScopeExperiment.Program.RunWithTransactionScope() in d:\vs-projects\TransactionScopeExperiment\TransactionScopeExperiment\Program.cs:line 81
```

My service looks something like this

```
[ServiceBehavior(TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable, TransactionTimeout = "00:01:00")]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.demo.com")]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public ServiceResponse ServiceMethod1(ServiceRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                // first SQL insert
                // second SQL insert fails and throws exception
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ServiceResponse(error: ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResponse ServiceMethod1(ServiceRequest request);
}

<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" transactionFlow="true">
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Why does ServiceMethod1 throw a ProtocolException instead of returning my error ServiceResponse object? How do I get my response object?**

Comment: Post the full exception ToString.

Comment: @usr I've added the full exception.ToString